# AudioQueue bytes to ffmpeg understandable WAV format

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, wav, audiotoolbox, audioqueueservices

I got the recorded *AudioQueueBufferRef* buffer using the following code.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer->mAudioData length:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize];
```

And then, I send the data to my server. However, FFMPEG isn't able to read that because the data is not in any audio standard format.

It's just plain data.

So, how do I do either on iPhone or backend ffmpeg to convert that raw buffer to WAV?

Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the WAV headers yourself. However, in a similar situation I chose to use the [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) command line tool. This is better for server side. You can take your raw audio data, save it to a file, and then execute the following command.

```
sox -r <your sample rate> -b <bytes per frame> -c <number of channels> -e <your sample encoding> <your raw audio file> <your-output-file.wav>
```

**Your raw audio file must have a .raw file extension.**

Comment: What would the sample encoding be?

Comment: It depends how your audio is encoded, but generally it is either `signed-integer` or `unsigned-integer` for PCM samples.